# ASP.NET MVC2 Multiple submit buttons, submit value null with FireFox and Chrome

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a form with multiple submit buttons:

```
using(Ajax.BeginForm("Submit", "myController", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{ %>
<button type="submit" name="submitType" value="submit_a">a</button>
<button type="submit" name="submitType" value="submit_b">b</button>
<% } %>
```

The controller method is as follows:

```
[Authorize, HandleError, HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(string submitType)
{
  //placeholder
}
```

With IE (js on or off) the buttons post back with their respective submitType value, however with Chrome and FireFox submitType is null (when js is on, it's fine when js is off)

Does anyone know how I can fix this behaviour please?

(Please note I need to use the Ajax form as it does partial postbacks/updates)

Comment: Have you tried replacing the button tag with an input tag? I vaguely recall some browser issue with using buttons rather than inputs.

Comment: I've tried it as both <button> and <input> tag's, both to no avail.  I'm quite certain it's related to Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleSubmit and I suspect there is some difference between IE and Chrome/FF which causes it to lose the submit control value

Answer (score 0):

Crap, the previous developer had placed the BeginForm() tags in invalid places (start of form tag in the middle of a div, end of form tag in an entirely seperate div) and whilst VS didn't throw any errors, it resulted in an invalid markup, which caused FireFox and Chrome to ignore and not return the submit value!
Once I corrected the tag positions it started working correctly.

Comment: Since this question is no longer valid, you should be able to delete your question with the link under your question (when logged in).